# Confused about Managed Identity and Access Control

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Little bit confused about how access is controlled using Azure App Registrations. I am experimenting and trying to clarify my understanding with a very basic example.

- I have created an Azure Data Factory resource (otestadf)
- Created an app registration (testappreg), this process also created an `applicationId` and a `secret`

Under role assignments for the ADF resource, `testappreg` is not listed but I can create a token like so and create an instance of `DataFactoryManagementClient`:

```
var tenant = "tenant";
var clientId = "client";
var secret = "super”_secret";

var client = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(secret)
    .WithAuthority($"https://login.windows.net/{tenant}")
    .Build();

var x = client.AcquireTokenForClient(new []{ "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
var accessToken = x.ExecuteAsync().Result.AccessToken; 

ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(accessToken);
var dmclient = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred) { SubscriptionId = "sub_id" };
```

I would have expected this to fail as I have not granted the app access to ADF under the `role assignments`.

Is it related to using `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` as the scope?

** EDIT **

Managed to get it working by doing this (note the scope of https://management.azure.com/.default)

```
        var cred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenant, clientId, secret);
        var ctx = new TokenRequestContext(new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" });
        var token = await cred.GetTokenAsync(ctx);
        var mgmtToken = new TokenCredentials(token.Token);
        var client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(mgmtToken) { SubscriptionId = "SUB_ID" };
        var response = await client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(
            "test",
            "otestadf",
            "foobar");
```

[image]

Comment: `I would have expected this to fail as I have not granted the app access to ADF under the role assignments` - It won't fail during the process of token generation however you should get an error when using the token (most likely 401).

Comment: I invoked the pipeline and was correctly getting an authentication failure. However, I added the app to role assignments (Data Factory Contributor) but still get authentication failed.

Comment: That could be because of incorrect scope (`https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`). Please try by getting a token for correct scope. I am not sure but please try with `https://management.azure.com/` or `https://management.core.windows.net/` as scope.

Comment: Its saying I have invalid scope. How do I know what the scope should be set to? Is there a list / documetation for this?

Comment: @GauravMantri had to use https://management.azure.com/.default to get token generation to work and its now working as expected.

Comment: @DrSchizo Good to post your solution as an answer for the community benefits with the same issue.

Comment: @NaveenSharma question was edited to include how to fix the problem

Comment: It would be great if the same was posted as an answer, as the community looking for Answered tag can land on this page for the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope was incorrect, it needed to be **https://management.azure.com/.default**

```
        var cred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenant, clientId, secret);
        var ctx = new TokenRequestContext(new string[] { "https://management.azure.com/.default" });
        var token = await cred.GetTokenAsync(ctx);
        var mgmtToken = new TokenCredentials(token.Token);
        var client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(mgmtToken) { SubscriptionId = "SUB_ID" };
        var response = await client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(
            "test",
            "otestadf",
            "foobar");
```